# AppstoreConnect reports total estimate proceeds in euro

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

We changed to a new developer account for one of our projects and somehow the payment & finance reports are in USD instead of euro (what was on our old account).

How can I see the proceeds in euro so we know how much we can expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes patience is key. The USD changed into euro's automatically after a few hours.